# Dynamically change the column name in a custom expression using $map in Spotfire

Tags: spotfire

I have a property that contains a list of column names and I want to create a custom expression using the `$map` function, like this

```
$map("Sum(${myproperty}) as [${myproperty}]", ",")
```

However, I would like to change the column names dynamically when they contain a given string.

I have tried the following, which however doesn't work as it returns the expression between `[]`

```
$map("Sum(${myproperty}) as [if(Find('string',${myproperty}),'new name', 'old name')]"), ",")
```

I have also tried the following, but it seems that `$map()` does not accept  `Concatenate()`

```
$map(Concatenate("Sum(${myproperty}) as [",
     if(Find('string',${myproperty}),'new name', 'old name'), "]"), 
",")
```

Is it possible to realize what I am trying to do in Spotfire?

Comment: Can you post an example of what you have and what you want please?

Answer (score 0):

[This post](https://community.tibco.com/questions/dynamic-column-header-names-based-document-property) has an example ironpython script that can be used to change column headers, using document properties.

The script looks like this:

```
col=ActivedataTable.Columns["CurrentColumnName"]
ColName= ActivedataTable.Columns[col.Name].Properties["ExternalName"]
col.Name= "New Name"
```

It perhaps doesn't quite answer your question, but hopefully is useful.